# visual studio code not showing full paratheses using flutter

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, dart

I'm using visual studio code to build flutter applications but there is something that i don't like which is that when i close a snippet of code , it dosn't show both paranthese like in android studio , I'm not sure which setting is responsible for that , i would like to be able to move to new line without having to expand the whole snipper code to find from where to move to new line to create new widget , anyone help is appreciated , thank you .

- This is a screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this setting in `settings.json`

`"editor.foldingStrategy": "indentation"`

[image: Screenshot]

This will add the ending parenthesis below the line :

[image: Screenshot 2]